# Why are my PHP/AJAX with JSONP scripts returning HTML, JSON, and invalid JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am having some trouble with communication between my php script and my javascript file.  It seems the javascript is receiving html, json, and "invalid json" from the php script that I have written.

In the Javascript code, the *data* variable evaluates to:

> {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}

This is not of the JSON format that I echo below (in either spot in the code where I do so).  Based on my research, this is because the JSON echo in the PHP code is returning invalid JSON (which causes the PHP to return this as a result instead).  However, when I check the console, I find the following:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli() [<a href='mysqli.mysqli'>mysqli.mysqli</a>]: (28000/1045): Access denied for ... in <b>..../.php</b> on line <b>xx</b><br />
{"status":"failure","message":"Access denied for ...."}
```

This is not printed because of any console.log statements I have in my code, this is printed as a result of Firefox's automatic console entry from the GET http://...../.php call.

The top line of code is the html that the PHP would return if this were not a JSON return, and the bottom line of the code above is the actual JSON object that I have created, and that I want to work with.

The reason I am posting here is because I cannot think of why the PHP would return html, my JSON, and JSON indicating invalid JSON.

I should also mention that I am receiving another error on the console:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' --> file.php:1

This suggests to me that the browser is trying to interpret the php on the client end for some reason, but I'm not sure if that's accurate or not.

I think that I have an error somewhere that is the root of all of these symptoms, but after some time and research, I have not been able to find this error on my own.

The code I am using is shown below:

Javascript AJAX:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "...url.../file.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        name: email,
        email: email
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //this is where the {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"} appears
    }

});
```

PHP (contents reduced to scope of this problem):

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=\"gamesUser.json\"");

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');

.........

$data = array();

$conn = @new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

//check the connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $data['status'] = 'failure';
    $data['message'] = $conn->connect_error;

    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    .........

    $data['status'] = 'success';
    $data['message'] = 'operations complete';
    $data['fileURL'] = $fileURL;

    echo json_encode($data);

    .........
}

.........
?>
```

SOLVED!

The code:

```
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).')';
```

along with changing ajax parameters:

```
type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'handleResponse',
    data: data
```

Have fixed the problems.  Thanks to everyone who assisted in the discussion.

Comment: That expecting '<' sounds like you've not escaped something so it's not executing correctly. Can you post the code of the file that produces that error?

Comment: That file would be the php file, where I've included the code above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When an error happens in PHP, it displays the error information using HTML so you can see it properly in the browser. That's why you get the unexpected HTML, so you should make sure the PHP script doesn't show errors

You can suppress warnings for mysqli constructor (which I think is the one causing the problem) by prepending the at (`@`) sign:

`...
@mysqli(...)
...`

There are other ways of avoid showing errors, check http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Thanks.  When I did that, it suppressed the html, but interestingly enough, it also suppressed my JSON object (the one that I want, as described above, not the "readyState" one).  For reference, I have included the connection call (with the @) in the code above.

Comment: @BrandonDixon My bad, I didn't check all your code, you should replace `complete` for `success`, since the first one doesn't really give you the data but the status

Comment: I need to keep it this way for now, because I haven't set up my php script to properly return status of success or failure (my webhost is using an older version of PHP, so I was having a bit of difficulty, and decided to handle success or failure in the complete function).  The JSON object I return from the PHP, and that I'm trying to get from the AJAX, will give me the status, as well as the data.

Comment: `success` doesn't depend on your server, it's a callback that jQuery executes if the request succeeds (both code 200 and data of the type you expected). `complete` is executed if the request ends (it doesn't matter if it's right or wrong). If you still need the `complete` then also use the `success` so you can see the response

Comment: Ok.  Upon changing it to success, nothing happens.  It does not execute any of the code I have under the success parameter.

Comment: Also, I now get an error message, which reads:{"status":"failure","message":"Access denied for ....."} --> that is the JSON object I want, but it appears as an error message, and I can't seem to access it with the javascript.

Comment: Which line is the one printing that error? I think it's not really an error but the actual response, but you `stringify`it, which is why you can't access it as an object. Try using: `console.log(data);` in the `success`

Comment: Ok.  I am now using a console.log("test") and console.log(data) to ensure that the function is actually executing (the success function).  No "test" appears on the command line, which leads me to think that the function is not being called.  I believe the web browser itself is printing that error message.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot it was a JSONP request. So the PHP should answer as if it's calling a Javascript function, like `update({x:1})`. So, you should reply like this: `echo $_GET['callback']. '(' .json_encode($data). ')';`. Make sure you check `$_GET['callback']` is a valid Javascript identifier before returning, as it could lead to attacks. `$_GET['callback']` is automatically sent by jQuery

Comment: Yes, that's what solved it!  The echo $_GET('callback').  That, in combination with the answer below.

Comment: Cool. Keep in mind `jsonp` isn't required, it's the name of the `GET` variable containing the name of the callback function, which defaults to `callback`. You also don't need to set `jsonpCallback`, it's the name of the function which is going to be called, which defaults to some random name made up by jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think , what you need is the `callback` function from `jsonp` , please go through the below example , you will get the idea

```
function myfunc(json) {
  alert(json);
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com?keyword=r&callback=jsonp",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'myfunc', // the function to call
  jsonp: 'callback', // name of the var specifying the callback in the request
})
```

;

Comment: After trying your suggestion, I receive: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}.  JSONP is needed in this case because at the moment, I am making this request cross-domain.

Comment: Where does the "jsonp": false, flag go?  I tried to place it in the data field, and as its own parameter, and neither made a difference.

Comment: I changed my code to match your suggestion above, and the function 'myfunc' is not actually executing.  Can you tell me exactly how the callback variable acts in this case?  EDIT: I would say that worked the same as my original method, which could imply that perhaps, the problem is with the PHP file instead.